# Displaying many ROC-curves

Tags: plotting, visualization

I did a classification using `Classify`. I sampled 20 times. To calculate the mean accuracy, etc., is easy. But is there also a way to overlay the calculated ROC curves? If one uses `Overlay` the output is not really pretty

[image]

I think it would be nice the overlay the graphs with decreasing opacity, so that one could see the different curves. I tried with `Opacity` but could not get it to work.

## Edit:

I made some sample data available here: [Klick](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o9464eddgqs4s1z/AAAOX7BizcYyhsgyknwB_0ADa?dl=0) It lasted a while to generate it -  I usually have more than 5GB, this is now about 5MB. For whose who do not want to download, here a few lines of code to generate an example:

```
dataset = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "Titanic"}, "Data"];
```

classifier functions:

```
cfuns = Table[
   Classify[dataset[[1 ;; 500]], Method -> "DecisionTree"], {3}];
```

classifier measures:

```
cmeasures = ClassifierMeasurements[#, dataset[[501 ;;]]] & /@ cfuns;
```

extract plots:

```
plots = Through[cmeasures["ROCCurve"]];
plots = #["died"] & /@ plots
```

delivers three ROC curves, to be combined:

[image]

Comment: If this is a question about plotting, it should include the necessary data to be used for the plot.

Comment: To come up with an answer, most of us would want to run tests with your code and your data. But you give us no code and no data. I think you are unlikely to get an answer unless you edit your question to provide the code you to make the plot you posted. It should  include a the data needed to reproduce your plot..

Comment: Instead of overlaying many plots, you should have a list of lists of curve data i.e you have  `curves = {{curve1}, {curve2}, ... , {curveN}}` and just plot `curves` once. You'll get coloured curves out, but you can use a single colour by adding `PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[.1]]`.  You can add the line with `Epilog -> Line[{{0,0}, {1,1}}]`

Comment: @m_goldberg Just edited the question with example data - this took a while - unfortunately.

Comment: @flinty. The problem is I have easily to access curves. The output here is an object with Head `Legended` which wraps a Graphics and so on... To pull out the curve did not work as I expected.

Comment: It's hacky, but you should try: `SortBy[#, First] & /@ plots[[All, 1, 1, 2, 1]]` which appears to extract the line out of the graphics - see here: https://pastebin.com/7jddYrr1 - if anybody has time, maybe this could be fleshed out into a full answer.

Comment: @flinty. This is a solution one only needs `Show[{ListPlot[out], Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]]}, 
 GridLines -> {{1}, {1}}]` and done. Thank you! I tried to extract the lines by `Cases...`, your solution is much simpler.